# Add class in parent when id is match

Tags: jquery

How to add class in parent when id is matched. eg [Link](http://spookadar.com/listing/pasadenas-suicide-bridge/) drag to bottom check video corner there are three tabs #1, #2, & #3. When user enter a value only two tabs then show two tabs in front end. At this time display all three tabs. All three video on this [Link](http://spookadar.com/listing/b-29-super-fortress-castle-air-museum/.)

Comment: Provide some code and what you have tried

Comment: http://awesomescreenshot.com/07f5fu5z86
http://spookadar.com/listing/pasadenas-suicide-bridge/ here the link i want when only one video found then #1 only display on top.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code sample as shown below:

```
$("#yourDomElementId").parent().addClass("classYouWantToAdd");
```

Comment: Please send me full example in jsfiddle